# Ruby Twitter API - bad request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twitter

Trying to use Twitter gem for rails 4 to let users search twitter for tweets containing a keyword. I've done my best to following the instructions in the API, but am obviously getting something wrong.

My Questions controller is returning the following error: Twitter::Error::BadRequest at /questions.

"Query parameters are missing"

I have a Twitter initialiser with all the oauth and app key/secret.

Here's my controller code:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
require 'twitter'

def new
    @question = Question.new
end

def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question.return = Twitter.search(params[:search])
    if @question.save
        redirect_to question_path(@question)
    end
end

def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @questions = Question.all
end

private
def question_params
   params.require(:question).permit(:search)
end
end
```

And my views: new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @question do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :search, :width => '100' %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= @question.id %></br>
<%= @question.search %></br>
<%= @question.return %></br>
<%= @question.created_at %></br>
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @questions.each do |q| %>
<%= q.search %>
<%= q.return %>
<% end %>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware the only parameter that the Twitter API requires for doing a search is the query itself, as in, a string. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search if you haven't already.

Are you maybe submitting the form with no query?